# Why we have target_size for DeepLab while CNN can accept any sizes?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I still have not understood a concept. One reason that we use fully convolutional layer at the end in a CNN network is to handle different images sizes during training. My question is that if this is the case why we always crop or squeeze images into squared sizes in the input section. Please do not say the question is repeated, we use squared images to make it easier, check pyramid pooling, and so on.

For example, Here's [a link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/deeplab_demo.ipynb#scrollTo=edGukUHXyymr)

DeepLab can accept any images with different sizes. But in its code, there is a target_size as (513). Now, if CNN can accept images with different sizes, why we need to use target_size. If this is for converting images into a standard format, why 513?
During training, we should specify batch size. What is our batch_size in this case: (5, None, None, None). Is it possible to have images with different sizes in a batch? 
I read many posts and still, I am confused with these questions:
- How can we train a model on images with different sizes (imagine that sizes are standard)? I see some codes use a batch size of one. I think it is not a solution. 
- Is there any snipped code that shows how can we define batches for a model like FCN to accept dataset with different sizes?
- In this paper: Here's [a link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4729) my problem was explained but authors again resized images into squared format, if we can use batches comprises of images with different sizes why they proposed that idea of using squared images between 180 by 180 and 224 by 224.

Has DeepLab used this part: [link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/deeplab_demo.ipynb#scrollTo=edGukUHXyymr) to make images into a standard format? or for other reason?

```
width, height = image.size
resize_ratio = 1.0 * 513 / max(width, height)
target_size = (int(resize_ratio * width), int(resize_ratio * height))
```

I could not find the place of their code when they training the model on PASCAL dataset.

I expected to find a simple code for Keras or Tensorflow whereas it shows easily that we can apply a CNN model such as FCN or DeepLab for a dataset such as PASCAL VOC2012 (for Segmentation) with images of different sizes without any resizing or cropping. Still, I am looking.
Thank you for detail answers in advance. Please do not repeat answers like you can use batch size one, squared images are common and better, you can add black margins to the images, fully connected layer is the problem, you can use global max pooling, and so on. I am looking to find a code that works on images with different sizes. 
I could not find the place of DeepLab model in TensorFlow GitHub where it accepts batches with different sizes?? [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab)

Also in here [FCN](https://github.com/aurora95/Keras-FCN) it is trained on COCO dataset with target_size of 320 by 320. Why? it should be any size for FCN.

Also, could one explain to me how can we have a batch of images with different sizes? Could we have an np array of different sized images? Batch = [5, none, none, 3]  each of 5 with different sizes.

I also found another confusing part in semantic segmentation. Using Keras Augmentation we can not augment image with more than 4 channels. It means that using Keras augmentation, we can not train PASCAL dataset with 21 channels. ??